# Vowpal Wabbit Matrix Factorization on one label

Tags: machine-learning, vowpalwabbit, matrix-factorization

What I'm after is a recommender system for the web, something like "related products". Based on the items a user has bought I want to find related items based on what other users has bought. I've followed the MovieLens tutorial (https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit/wiki/Matrix-factorization-example) for making a recommender system.

In the example above the users gave the movies a score (1-5). The model can then predict the score a user will give a specific item.

My data, on the other hand, only knows what the user likes. I don't know what they dislike or how much they like something. So I've tried sending 1 as the value on all my entries, but that only gives me a model that returns 1 on every prediction.

Any ideas on how I can structure my data so that I can receive prediction on how likely it is for the user to like an item between 0 and 1?

Example data:

```
1.0 |user 1 |item 1
1.0 |user 1 |item 2
1.0 |user 2 |item 2
1.0 |user 2 |item 3
1.0 |user 3 |item 1
1.0 |user 3 |item 3
```

Training command:

```
cat test.vw | vw /dev/stdin -b 18 -q ui --rank 10 --l2 0.001 --learning_rate 0.015 --passes 20 --decay_learning_rate 0.97 --power_t 0 -f test.reg --cache_file test.cache
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Short answer to the question:

To get a prediction resembling "probabilities" you could use `--loss_function logistic --link logistic`. Be aware that in this single-label setting your probabilities risk tending to 1.0 quickly (i.e. become meaningless).

## Additional notes:

- Working with a single label is problematic in the sense that there's no separation of the goal.  Eventually the learner will peg all predictions to 1.0.  To counter that - it is recommended to use `--noconstant`, use strong regularization, decrease the learning rate, avoid multiple passes, etc. (IOW: anything that avoids over-fitting to the single label)
- Even better: add examples where the user hasn't bought/clicked, they should be plentiful, this will make your model much more robust and meaningful.
- There's a better implementation of matrix factorization in `vw` (much faster and lighter on IO for big models).  Check the `--lrq` option and the full demo under `demo/movielens` in the source tree.
- You should pass the training-set directly to `vw` to avoid [Useless use of cat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)#Useless_use_of_cat)